# <table> height 100% inside a <td> is not working in IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer, html-table

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
    <style>
    html,body, #outer, .innerPages {height:100%; padding:0px; width:100%; }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <table id="outer">
    <tr height="100px"><td>Header</td></tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <table class="innerPages">
             <tr>
               <td>Left</td>
               <td>Right</td>
             </tr>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
    <tr height="30px"><td>Footer</td></tr>
    </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you add a height of 100% to the td it should work in IE.

See my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZGP3K/2/

As you can see in the html, I changed your header a bit too.